# Twitter Bootstrap: Most IE related issue happen in local server

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap

after several days with a lot of IE problem, i found out that the script does not work well in my Localhost.

Here's to replicate my issue:
download original bootstrap (with docs)
Run the docs on localhost, and upload the docs on 'online' server..

and i see several different layout, like no arrows on sub-menu, etc... but there's no problem with online docs

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Probably some CDN stuff isn't linked properly in your local version.

Comment: this does not happen on IE9, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari... could it be CDN stuff problem, or something in IE8 setting blocks ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your paths? If images aren't showing it sounds like they're not in the right place. If your localhost isn't set up correctly using, for example, `/` to find the root might not take you where you expect to go. If you have Firebug try inspecting the element with that and seeing where it is looking for the image/styles/js and check your paths are correct.

Comment: Nope.. i think the paths is correct, as there's no problem in Chrome/Firefox/Safari... only happen in IE8 (even in IE9 is working)

Answer (score 0):

If you still have IE8 please try to download:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/master

and try to run docs/components.html in your IE8 local